# C++ Warning: Initializing truncation from double to float in one declaration but not in another

Tags: c++

Here is the code in question:

```
static const float SMALL_BINDING_TARGET_SIDE =              10;
static const float SMALL_BINDING_TARGET_HS =                0.25;
static const float SMALL_BINDING_TARGET_HL =                2.6;
static const float SMALL_BINDING_TARGET_VS =                1.33;
static const float SMALL_BINDING_TARGET_VL =                3.54;
```

The problem is that my compiler (using Qt with MVSC 2017) throws this warning:

```
warning: C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
```

In the lower three lines but it does not in the upper two. Morever I have a total 16 declarations exactly like this (including the 5 in the code above) and it is only those three that generate the warning.

Can anyone tell me the difference and what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify that you literals are floats by adding `f`. So a line will look like this:

```
static const float SMALL_BINDING_TARGET_SIDE =              10.f;
```

Without that f, the literals are interpreted to  be double precision and may truncate if the binary representation is longer as the float precision.

This does not occur, as the upper two can be represented in binary without using many bits, hence fitting in the float without truncation.

Comment: First two are fully representable, no data loss

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I tried to say that. Is it unclear?

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

First two literals are fully representable by float. Actually, first one in an integer and second one is a power of two. Warning appears when value you specify results in binary representation that would not fit into float without truncating some bits. Conversion from double to float is expensive and in any other case you would want to avoid it.

You can suppress warning by passing float literal, e.g.`1.33f` would generate float representation, closest to value you specify.